# Returning Value(all fields) from Datatable to AJAX in ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I've searched all over the net but I didn't find the answer maybe you guys can help. I am new to ASP.NET C#

My aspx.cs code

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static string GetData(int ID)
{
    string SQL = "Select ID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName from tbl_demo1 where ID = '" + ID + "'";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, cn);
    da.Fill(dt);
    if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        return dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Question:in this part

```
return dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
```

In this part I want to return all fields(ID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName) .. How would I do it?

Comment: You want to return only one row or all rows?

Comment: i want to return only one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the part of code that you asked:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
   string str = row["ID"].ToString() + row["FirstName"].ToString() + row["MiddleName"].ToString() + row["LastName"].ToString();
   return str;
}
```

If you want to return it as an KVP array, use like below

```
SortedList<string, string> rowObj = new SortedList<string, string>();
rowObj.Add("ID", row["ID"].ToString());
rowObj.Add("FirstName", row["FirstName"].ToString());
rowObj.Add("MiddleName", row["MiddleName"].ToString());
rowObj.Add("LastName", row["LastName"].ToString());
return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(rowObj));
```

Can be called using jQuery:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "YourFileService.asmx/GetData",
    data: "{'ID':" + ID + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (typeof data.d != "undefined") {
            var res = JSON.parse(data.d);
            alert(res.FirstName)
        } else {
            if (window.console) {
                console.log('Unknown error,');
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
        //raise an error
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        //failure, raise an error
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works..... how can i call it from jquery like this ?alert(data.Firstname)

Comment: is it ok if i use url: "YourFileService.aspx/GetData", instead of url: "YourFileService.asmx/GetData",?? it says undefine

Comment: Just change it to your file name where you have function. If you use URL, it will case cross domain issue.

Comment: it says "undefined" for alert(res.FirstName)

Comment: Can you try it by updating this line: var res = JSON.parse(data.d);

Comment: Good to hear that, so accept the answer then. Thanks.